# Why is a DataFrameStatFunctions object not equal to a copy of itself?

Tags: python, pyspark

In pyspark, the DataFrame class has an Attribute `stat`.  Calling it creates an object of type DataFrameStatFunctions.
I created a DataFrame called `df`, and then ran the following code:

```
dfstat = df.stat
dfstat == df.stat
```

The result came back `False`.  I believe this has to do with pointers, or maybe shallow copies or something.  Can anyone help me understand why the `stat` attribute of a pyspark DataFrame is not equal to a copy of itself?

[stat attribute source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrameStatFunctions)
[DataFrame documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html)

Comment: The class does not implement an `__eq__()` method, so its instances cannot compare as equal to any other object, no matter how similar you might consider them to be.  Presumably the programmer didn't think that equality comparisons would be needed for these objects.

Comment: @jasonharper The DataFrame class also does not appear to have an `__eq__()` method, and yet I seem to be able to compare two of them and get `True` back.  Are you sure that  an `__eq__()` method is required for comparisons?   https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame